# Freeze columns from Excel SQL Query

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have an Excel SQL query made using the Query wizard / power query. Sometimes, when I refresh the data, the columns shuffle order! I have already tried checking/unchecking "preserve column sort" as suggested here: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/sql-changing-column-order-when-put-into-excel.207385/

Comment: 1. Try to walk through your code with F8 and find out the moment when columns are sorted/ changing their order. 2. Share us your code to see possible issues.

Comment: What is the query, is it `Select *` or `Select [field1]….` ?

Comment: It's Select [field1], [field2]... so I'd expect it to stay frozen.

Answer (score 0):

@Nathan brings up a good point. Try specifying in the query itself, the order of the columns.

If that does not work, The solution would be to accomodate the different order of columns as a possible outcome every time by making the result query into a ListObject Table. (I believe you can check this as part of the Query Wizard, to import as Table)

Then you can use the name of the columns without knowing the range address in your worksheet formulas and VBA code. You could simply refer to the column name in the format shown in this tutorial, then get the properties for column or row number using any number of methods.

[Tutorial on using ListObject Tables](https://exceljet.net/excel-tables)

Comment: Yes, it's being imported as a Table object currently.